# How can I start a batch script with elevated permissions remotely with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script which needs to run a batch on multiple remote Computers. That batch scripts needs to run with Domain Admin privileges.

Is it even possible to achieve this with the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet?

I already enabled WinRM on the remote machine so I don't think that's the problem.

```
$computername = Read-Host "Enter Hostname"

$user = "mydomain\administrator"
$pwd = Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$user", $pwd)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    $remoteuser = "mydomain\administrator"
    $remotepwd = Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString
    $remotecred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$remoteuser", $remotepwd)

    $script = "\\path_to_script\script.bat"

    Start-Process $script -Credential $cred1    
}
```

I expect the script to run under the domain admin credentials on the remote machine. Instead I get this error:

> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-Process], UnauthorizedAccessException
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
>   PSComputerName        : mycomputername

Answer (score 2):

Your `$cred1` variable doesn't exist, it should be `$remotecred`:

```
Start-Process $script -Credential $remotecred
```

The variable name `$pwd` is reserved for 'print working directory'.

You can see this by running a new powershell console and querying it, you'll get a value for the current working directory:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $pwd

Path
----
C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

Use something different like `$pass` instead.

I would also call `CMD` and pass your batch file in using `/c` ([documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)):

```
Start-Process CMD -ArgumentList "/c $script" -Credential $remotecred
```

---

Putting all this into practice:

```
$computername = Read-Host "Enter Hostname"

$user = "mydomain\administrator"
$pass = Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $pass)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    $remoteuser = "mydomain\administrator"
    $remotepwd = Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString
    $remotecred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$remoteuser", $remotepwd)

    $script = "\\path_to_script\script.bat"

    Start-Process CMD -ArgumentList "/c $script" -Credential $remotecred
}
```

---

If you are actually using the same credentials for the remote session as you are to launch the batch file, then you don't need the second set of credentials.

As the remote session is running as `mydomain\administrator` any processes it spawns will also run as that user:

```
$computername = Read-Host "Enter Hostname"

$user = "mydomain\administrator"
$pass = Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $pass)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername  -ScriptBlock {
    $script = "\\path_to_script\script.bat"

    Start-Process CMD -ArgumentList "/c $script"
}
```